# UICollectionView doesn't reload items when containing a header

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data, ios6, uicollectionview

***Edit:** The initial question was wrong, so some of the content might be a bit unrelated. But might give you a better impression of the way I'm doing stuff.*

I've got a pretty strange problem with a `NSFetchedResultsController`. First I'll describe the current situation of my app. I've got multiple `Album` and `Photo` entities, which are both subclasses of an abstract class `AbstractItem`.

In my `AlbumViewController` I'm using to a `NSFetchedResultsController` to get all the `AbstractItem`'s with the current `superAlbum`. Like this:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {
    if (!fetchedResultsController ) {
        NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

        [request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"AbstractItem"
                                       inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext]];

        [request setSortDescriptors:@[
         [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"type" ascending:YES],
         [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES],
         [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"creationDate" ascending:YES]
        ]];

        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"superAlbum = %@", self.parentAlbum];
        [request setPredicate:predicate];

        NSFetchedResultsController *newController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request
                                                                                        managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext
                                                                                          sectionNameKeyPath:@"type"
                                                                                                   cacheName:nil];

        newController.delegate = self;

        self.fetchedResultsController = newController;
    }

    return fetchedResultsController;
}
```

When I select an `Album`, another instance of `AlbumViewController` is initiated and pushed on my navigation controller. In that case `parentAlbum` is set to the selected object.

Now when I add a new `Album` with the following code, the error occurs.

```
Album *album = (Album *)[Album itemInManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
album.name = @"Test album";
album.superAlbum = self.parentAlbum;

NSError *error;
BOOL success = [self.managedObjectContext save:&error];

if (!success) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}
```

<strike>The method `controller:didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType:newIndexPath:` gets called for with the type `NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate` for the `parentAlbum` object. That one's isn't present in the current `NSFetchedResultsController`. So it fails when it tries to update it in the collection view.</strike>

How is it possible that an object that isn't in the current `NSFetchedResultsController` is used for a notification? And how can I fix this issue?

**Edit:**
After posting the question, I realized that it actually isn't the `NSFetchedResultsController` notifying about the wrong object. But it notifies about an object in the previous (parent) collection view, but it does that to it's own collection view controller.

But that might be just the problem; The collection view controller receives a notification while it isn't visible, looks like it can't handle that at this moment. I handle the notification like this:

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {    
    switch (type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self.collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]];
            break;
    }
}
```

I was pretty sure it worked fine before. After iterating over the changes made since last commit, I get it to work again. It did work again after I removed the `UICollectionView` header (the supplementary view).

So: My `UICollectionView` can't update items when it has an header and it's not currently visible. That was a tough one to discover, but how can this be fixed? Think it's a really strange issue.

The errors I get:

```
2012-10-04 11:54:21.148 PhotoLibrary[9195:c07] -[NSISObjectiveLinearExpression coefficientForVariable:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x968bae0
2012-10-04 11:54:21.151 PhotoLibrary[9195:c07] CoreData: error: Serious application error.  Exception was caught during Core Data change processing.  This is usually a bug within an observer of NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.  -[NSISObjectiveLinearExpression coefficientForVariable:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x968bae0 with userInfo (null)
2012-10-04 11:54:21.156 PhotoLibrary[9195:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSISObjectiveLinearExpression coefficientForVariable:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x968bae0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2977012 0x1418e7e 0x2a024bd 0x2966bbc 0x296694e 0xcb06c3 0xcb569c 0xcbf88e 0x58c670 0x5945bd 0x29198fd 0x594605 0x29198fd 0x594605 0x29198fd 0x594605 0x5946c7 0x9cd53 0x5525ff 0x9ea5c 0x5522f7 0x565228 0x56231b 0x55ed4e 0x55edf0 0x8f56 0x1242c1a 0xbcddc9 0x29d10c5 0x292befa 0xb02482 0x11545f3 0x11ede5f 0x114fa26 0x115316e 0x55dc 0x85e5 0x4312c1 0x142c705 0x57920 0x578b8 0x118671 0x118bcf 0x117d38 0x8733f 0x87552 0x653aa 0x56cf8 0x20badf9 0x20baad0 0x28ecbf5 0x28ec962 0x291dbb6 0x291cf44 0x291ce1b 0x20b97e3 0x20b9668 0x5465c 0x26bd 0x25e5)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

Comment: Do you get anything in the error at all when you are saving the managed object context? Also, what is `itemInManagedObjectContext:`? Judging by the exception, this is a core data problem and not a collection view problem.

Comment: Don't get any other errors, but the album won't get saved, so might be that the save method doesn't even get called? The method `itemInManagedObjectContext:` just calls `[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:entityName inManagedObjectContext:context]` and set some default values (like creationDate).

Comment: But everything works fine till it does the `[self.collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]];`, so I guess it's not really a Core Data problem. Also works fine without a header in the collection view.

Comment: Turn on exception breakpoints and see if it will break on the exact line that it doesn't like.

Comment: It breaks exactly on that line. I made a sample project: http://cloud.h-dev.nl/1x1W2t2y3p0d

Just add an event, tap it and add another. When you remove the header, it doesn't happen.

Comment: Using a FRC with UICollectionView seems to be a difficult topic, because UICollectionView does not have `beginUpdates`, `endUpdates` methods. Did you have a look at https://github.com/AshFurrow/UICollectionView-NSFetchedResultsController, where a workaround is described?

Comment: I did try Ash's approach, but that didn't do the trick. Still the same error after that reloadItems method. Think it's really strange that it only happens if there's a heade in the collection view.

Comment: I can confirm that this is a pure UICollectionView problem. I have removed all Core Data code from your sample project and just calling `insertItemsAtIndexPaths` or `performBatchUpdates` while the view is not visible causes the exception. So my answer is more a workaround than a solution. At present I assume that this is a bug in UICollectionView.

Comment: With your code, does it only happens when there's a header too?

Comment: Yes, no problem without header. From the stack backtrace I assume a bug in the layout calculation of the collection view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know if this is a solution or a workaround, but if you release the fetched results controller in `viewWillDisappear`:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    self.fetchedResultsController = nil;
}
```

then your ErrorTest program does not crash anymore and seems to work correctly.

This avoids updates to a collection view that is currently not visible.

Since you are already accessing the FRC in `viewWillAppear`:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    // ...    
    NSError *error = nil;
    BOOL success = [self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error];
    // ...
}
```

the FRC will re-created when the view becomes visible again, due to the lazy setter function of the FRC.

Comment: But it's actually a better approach to do it that way, right? Since it fetches the results when the view will appear.

Comment: Although, a fetch might be heavier than a few updates... So it might be not the ideal approach to refetch when you go back to the previous view controller.

Comment: @GuidoH: As I said, it is a workaround. And your code already did `performFetch` in `viewWillAppear`. - Actually it is sufficient to set `self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = nil` in `viewWillDisappear` to avoid updates to the view controller, so that you don't have to re-create the FRC in `viewWillAppear`. But if you set the delegate in `viewWillAppear` again, you have also to call `performFetch`, because the FRC does not track changes while is has no delegate.